How to restrict file size in a specified folder?
I need to restrict the size of every single file that is stored in a specific folder on our File Server. The main objective is to avoid large files being stored and transferred on the network. I've tried using File Screening Management in File Server Resource Manager (FSRM), but it only allows me to put restrictions based on file type and it allows to give a limit to Folder using Quota Template, but this cannot be applied to files.
The actual requirement is to enforce a size restriction on every file in the folder, regardless of the file type. For example, if I set the maximum file size to 5MB, it should check every file being saved, moved, or downloaded into the folder. If a file exceeds 5MB, it should trigger a warning message ideally, if that's not possible , then give a hard limit on the file operation and should not allow operation to succeed.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/storage/fsrm/file-screening-management
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/storage/fsrm/create-quota-template
We use Windows Server 2012R2
Is there any other method to achieve this using FSRM, or another method or tool that can accomplish this? Any guidance or detailed steps would be greatly appreciated!
Thank you!

No, FSRM or the old Disk Quota's windows are per users or per volume only. You will have to relay on a third party tool to achieve that, but I don't know if one exist.
As seen here you are not the only one that ask that, like to that question, but it's un-answered for more than one year.

There aren't any products that I am aware of that do (only) this that I am aware of. It would be fairly trivial to code. .NET has a file system watcher, you create it, specify the directory, and when a file is created it would be easy to take any action like delete or overwrite the file...

@GregAskew I agree! It would be a nice project to do, even on GitHub with multiple open source collaboration(s) to have a strong professional foothold. I stated it indirectly as it’s so niche that it’s to take precaution to use a product, if one found, on a server if in production.

Only a workaround with an upload page and IIS would be able to achieve it with the available components.

@GregAskew .NET has a file system watcher ... and when a file is created it would be easy to take any action like delete or overwrite the file...  Ooof.  Really?  So when someone uses rename to move an important, large file into some directory being watched and it gets deleted or overwritten?  Yeah, nuking the CEO's presentation to tomorrow's BoD meeting like that will go over well...
